# Why do we have different effect when setting pointer=nullpointer and pointer->next=nullpointer in linked list - C++

Tags: c++, pointers, singly-linked-list

I have the following code snippet (regarding singly linked list) -

```
class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

Node* newNode(int data)
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = nullptr;
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    Node* head = newNode(2);
    head->next = newNode(4);

    Node* p1 = head;
    p1 = nullptr;

    return 0;
}
```

Here, `head` and `p1` are separate variables - meaning separate memory location. So, when we do `p1=nullptr`, only `p1` should be effected, and not `head`. And, this is what happens, when I debug the code (as seen in the image below):

[image: Linked List when pointer set to null - head is not effected]

But, when I do p1->next=nullptr instead of p1=nullptr, head is also effected. As shown in the image below:

[image: head also effected]

p1 and head are different memory locations. Hence p1=nullptr does not effect head. But why does       p1->next=nullptr effect head?

p1 points to a string of pointers and head also points to a string of pointers (p1->next->next->next... and head->next->next->next...). p1 is at the same memory location as head. And p1->next and head->next are also at the same memory location (after we say p1=head), and so are the other next pointers. So, why does setting p1 to nullpointer (or any other value) does not effect head. But, setting p1->next to nullptr, effect head? If you could answer me with a boxed diagram for how the memory is working here, it will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misinterpreting what you're seeing in your debugger. `head` is unaffected.

The only thing that `head` is, by itself, is the memory address. Nothing more, nothing else.

In your second example, `head` must've been `0x007ce390` before `p1->next=nullptr`, and it is still the same exact memory address after is assignment.

What your debugger is helpfully showing you is not just the pointer itself, the actual memory address it's pointing to, but also what are all the values the pointer references. Since `p1` and `head` are now the same pointer, setting `p1->next=nullptr` also changes the values that `head` points to, and your debugger shows that.

But the pointer itself is unchanged.

Comment: Hi Sam, I understand that head is not being changed, but the head->next pointer is being changed in the second example (that is causing the first row in the locals window to show up in red). So, when we assign head to p1, essentially head and p1 are the same. So, when we do p1=nullptr after that (as in the first example), why doesn't head also become null?

Comment: @VikramSingh I think you are missing the fact that pointers are separate objects as well. You can have two pointers pointing to the same thing, no problem. You can change actual object using both of these pointers. But you can also change one of these pointers to point to something else, why not. Changes to pointers themselves do not change object pointed to, nor they don't change the other pointers pointing to that object. So `p1 = nullptr;` changes one of the pointers, but doesn't affect other pointers or pointee object. But `p1->next = nullptr;` changes the pointee object.